# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/missing-email). FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/missing-email)

Tags: angular, firebase

When I try to use the method signInWithEmailAndPassword, I get the following error:

(PS, I have imported the AngularFireAuthModule and created a user on Firebase
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';)

```
POST https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=AIzaSyAdy0AH46hWcBLMFXR57-FrruspopK-0ao 400
2core.mjs:7643 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/missing-email).
FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/missing-email).
    at createErrorInternal (index-6bd8d405.js:474:41)
    at _fail (index-6bd8d405.js:445:11)
    at index-6bd8d405.js:976:17
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js:3:1)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js:25:1)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:372:26)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.mjs:26291:33)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:371:52)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:134:43)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1211:31)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1165:17)
    at zone.js:1278:17
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:406:31)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:26278:33)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:405:60)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:178:47)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:585:35)
```

Here is the Auth Service.ts file:

```
export class AuthService {

  constructor( private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private toastr: ToastrService) { }

  login(email, password) {
    this.afAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(logRef => {
      this.toastr.success('Logged in Succesfully'); 
    });
  }
}
```

And here is the login component.ts file

```
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onSubmit(formValue) {
    this.authService.login(formValue.email, formValue.password); 

  }
}
```

I believe that for some reason FireBase DB is not connecting to my Angular app. Help please.

Comment: Can you print `email` and `password` before `this.afAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword` to ensure you're not sending `undefined` values...

Comment: How to do that? I am sorry, I am just a beginner.